# html - How to Overlap Div contain link over parent Div?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have div contain 2 Divs, one for **image-thumbnail** and another contain **link**. However, whenever i click link on **"the link-div"**, it always show modal window that i dont expect it. it should be opened link normally, not modal dialog. **FYI, The link opened normally by right click**. Below are the codes :

```
<div class="col-sm-4"> 
    <div  id="<?php echo $row['filename']?>" class="thumbnail" style="height:205px;width:337px;background-image:url('<?php echo base_url().'/uploads/thumb/'.$row['thumbnail']; ?>')">
        <div onClick="loadModal();" style="position: absolute;bottom:40%;left:40%;"> 
            <img  src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/uploads/thumb/play-button.png" />
        </div>
        <div style="z-index:1; position:relative;" class="thumb_text">
            <h5 >&nbsp;Kiriman : <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>cms/detail/<?php echo $row['iduser'];?>"><u><?php echo $row['nama'];?></u></a></h5>
        </div>
    </div>                   
</div>
```

The Modal Code :

```
function loadModal()
{
  $("div.modal-bg").show();
  $("div.modal-bg").fadeTo("slow", .5);
  $("div#simpleModal").addClass("show");
}
```

The CSS of the modal :

```
div#simpleModal.show
{
    opacity: 1; 
    z-index: 100;        
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s; 
}
```

I have include `style="z-index:1"` in the 2nd Div that contain link, but still failed.

Comment: Add `onClick="loadModal();"` to the `div` containing image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling `loadModal()` function from the parent `div`

So change your function like this

```
<div class="col-sm-4"> 
<div  class="thumbnail" style="height:205px;width:337px;background-image:url('<?php echo base_url().'/uploads/thumb/'.$row['thumbnail']; ?>')">
    <div onClick="loadModal();" id="<?php echo $row['filename']?>" style="position: absolute;bottom:40%;left:40%;"> 
        <img  src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/uploads/thumb/play-button.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="z-index:1" class="thumb_text">
        <h5 >&nbsp;Author : <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>cms/detail/<?php echo $row['iduser'];?>"><u><?php echo $row['name'];?></u></a></h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code `<div style="z-index:1; position:relative;" class="thumb_text">`
because z-index not working with static position( default position:static )

Comment: you think thats why its loading modal when clicking on link div??

Comment: @anoop LL sorry i was mistaken

Comment: @user2226388 still showing the modal?? if yes please post your loadModal() function